# Object in a vector c++

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, getter-setter

I am attempting to create a vector containing "Person" objects. It works fine when I don't use a vector and then instantiate people to display the result. My C++ is rusty, do I need to create a pointer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

class Person {
private:
    int age;
    string name;
public:
    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    string getName() {
        return name;

    }

    void setAgeName(int a, string n) {
        age = a;
        name = n;

    }
};

int main() {
    vector<Person> people;
    people[0].setAgeName(49, "Dudeman");

    cout << people[0].getName() << endl;
    cout << people[0].getAge() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is a blank terminal, If I remove all the vector business in main and treat it as a single object, it works fine. There must be something simple I'm missing.

Comment: `people` is an empty vector. Try `vector<Person> people(1);`

Answer (score 2):

`people` vector doesn't have a size yet. You need to `push_back` a `Person` object:

```
Person person;
vector<Person> people;

person.setAgeName(49, "Dudeman");
people.push_back(person);
```

Comment: Or, you can `resize()` the vector so it creates a `Person` for you: `vector<Person> people; people.resize(1);` or just `vector<Person> people(1);`